# Find number of ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_{12} \to \mathbb Z_{28}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, proof-verification

Find number of ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_{12} \to \mathbb Z_{28}$.

This question has been asked before but I found the solution confusing.Please check whether my approach is valid.

A ring homomorphism satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y);f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$

A ring homomorphism must first be a group homomorphism.

So $f$ will entirely depend upon its image on $[1]$.Now $o(f([1]))$ must divide both $12,28$.Hence $f([1])=0;f([1]=[7],f([1]=[14]$

But if we take $f([1])=[7] $ then it will fail to be ring homomorphism as $f[nm]=[7][nm]\neq [7m][7n]$

if we take $f([1])=[14] $ then it will fail to be ring homomorphism as $f[nm]=[14][nm]\neq [14m][14n]$

Thus only one available is $f([1])=[0]$ .Is it correct ?

Please help.

Comment: For Ring homomorphism you may also note that if  $f(1)=a$ then $a=f(1.1)=f(1)f(1)=a^2 $.

Comment: Not a duplicate; OP explicitly says they are aware of the duplicate but don't follow the argument given there.  Moreover, the question here is not "how do you solve this?" but "is this a valid way to solve the problem?".

Comment: A ring homomorphism should map $1$ to $1$, at least in the commutative context.

Comment: What specifically did you find confusing about one or more of the other four Answers to this problem?  Or what specifically do you feel doubtful about your own solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is totally valid.  However, you missed one possibility: $f([1])$ could also be $[21]$.  And in fact, this one works, since $[21][nm]=[21n][21m]$ for all $n,m$ (since $21^2\equiv 21$ mod $28$).  So besides the homomorphism sending $[1]$ to $[0]$, there's also one sending $[1]$ to $[21]$.

(All of this is assuming you are talking about *non-unital* homomorphisms.  It is actually very common to impose as part of the definition of "ring-homomorphism" that $f$ must send the multiplicative identity to itself.  In that case, the only option is $f([1])=[1]$, which doesn't work, since $28$ does not divide $12$.  So with that definition, there are *no* homomorphisms.)

Comment: is there any way to find the number of solutions of the equation $x^2-x\equiv 0$ in $\mathbb Z_{28}$

Comment: how did you know that $f[1]=[21]$ is an option ;Is that we have to individually check all the elements in the group whether it satisfies the criteria that $o(f[1])$ must divide both $28 $ and $12$ ?

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: Right, $[21]$ is just the the last element whose order divides both $28$ and $12$.

Comment: but checking all the elements in a group is cumbersome ;no alternative way

Comment: Well, the order of $[n]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{28}$ is just $28/\gcd(n,28)$.  You need this number to be $1$, $2$, or $4$, so you need $\gcd(n,28)$ to be $7$, $14$, or $28$.  In particular, $n$ has to be divisible by $7$, so there aren't very many to check.